# Which module system is fabric composer using for the logic JS files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to build a `business-network-definition` for Hyperledger using Fabric (based on [generator-hyperledger-fabric](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-hyperledger-composer)). So far it's worked pretty good, but now that we're working on a PoC, a couple of questions have come up:

1. Is the logic files (stored in the `/lib` dir) CommonJS modules? Mainly so we split them into reusable utilities to use within our transactions code.
2. Can we import and use NPM packages?
3. What's globally available in the logic files? I know there's some function callse like `getParticipantRegistry` or `getFactory` (among others), but where are they documented? Where can I get a detailed documentation about them? I'm happy reading code, I just need some one to nudge me into the right direction.

**NOTE** Please kindly let me know when and if any of my questions don't make sense, I'm still trying to learn Hyperledger and make something useful out of it ;) Also, feel free to point me to docs, I love reading docs, but for some reason I can't find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. they're not CommonJS modules per se - they're JS script files. In future releases of Composer there will be the ability to use `requires` and use modules. Current smart contract / transaction logic is written as one or more .js files in the `lib/` directory and deployed to the Composer runtime on the blockchain network (the business network is replicated to the peers and whatever channel was defined).
2. As above - in a later release you will be able to do this and be able to write native NodeJS chaincode.
3. See the API reference -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/api/api-doc-index and also here for searching on the modules and classes etc. -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/jsdoc/ - our main docs site (with concepts and architecture info is here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer